# Can kubernetes sidecar container send a unix signal to other container process?

Tags: kubernetes

I wanted to understand if a sidecar container can send a unix signal to the main container process).

The use-case is I have Nginx running as the main content serving app container and I want the sidecar container to receive Nginx config updates and reload Nginx by sending a signal. These two containers would be running in a single pod.

PS: I don't have an environment to try this out but wanted to check if people have used such a pattern?

Answer (score 6):

You can share process namespace by setting `shareProcessNamespace: true`.

The Kubernetes documentation has an example where a sidecar sends a `SIGHUP` to an nginx container in the same pod: [Share Process Namespace between Containers in a Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/#configure-a-pod). As shown in the example, you might to add some capabilities to the container.